# How to talk to a friend that just lost an eye

Tags: disability

My friend just lost an eye on an accident and I don't know how to deal with it or what to tell him. He seems to have a good sense of humor about it but I can only imagine how bad it feels.

Is there any specific stuff I should be aware of, or topics I should avoid?

Comment: This depends very much on your friend. Some people want to talk about their fate, others don't and rather want to go back to normality as good as possible. A general answer can't be given. It's even hard to give answers in a "I could imagine... " style in this case, even if they were wanted in this forum.

Comment: I think there may be an interesting core question here, about talking to people that recently have had a pretty traumatic injury that may have an impact on them for the rest of their lives, from an [tag:academic-research] point of view. Perhaps it's a good idea to run that through the [Sandbox](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3129/1599) first though, for further fine-tuning. But I'm pretty sure there's research based guidelines for nurses and family members on how to approach such situations out there!